# Unable to load one or more of the requested types - IIS - windows server 2012

Tags: iis

I am getting this error when I just browse  https://hostname or https://hostname/myapplicaation or https://ipaddress/myapplication , but it works when I browse using https with localhost https://localhost/myapplication.
It always works for http browsing. Please suggest any answers for this

Comment: Added bindings for the hostname and protocols inIIS?

Comment: Is this the error message in the [Administrative Tools] Event Viewer?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @chetan : yes it works, thank you very much for the solution